# Django not routing Heroku Websokect to dyno

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-channels

I am trying to enable Channels V2 for a Django app deployed in Heroku.
The WSGI web dyno works perfectly but the second web dyno for ASGI channels never get the requests so when trying to create a websocket connection I get a 404 response.

**Here is the Procfile file:**

```
web: gunicorn app_xxx.wsgi --log-file -
web2: daphne app_xxx.routing:application --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
```

I have also tried with Uvicorn like:

```
web: gunicorn app_xxx.wsgi --log-file -
web2: gunicorn app_xxx.asgi:application -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT -w 1 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker
```

Seems like everything is in place, just need to find a way to EXPOSE the wss endpoint

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

In order to make Channels works on Heroku you should first add a Redis add-on then make sure your `CHANNEL_LAYERS` variable in your **settings.py** points to this redis host machine. Below you can see an example:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [config('CHANNEL_LAYERS_HOST')],
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: Can you give more infor specifically the correct Procfile to use to run a django site + channels websocket?